# CSS why table border appeared in an child absolute positioned element?

Tags: html, css

my main goal is to make an pop up action with focus element. but it seems the table border is appear in the action box even the action box has no transparency property. shown in red box[image] image below. i want the action box is completely in top of table element so the table border not visible at the action box. i have tried to use z-index on action box, but it's not work.

here is my code for action box

```css
.action {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 120px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 200ms linear;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 200ms linear;
}

.action ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.action ul li {
  height: 44px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
}

.action ul li a {
  line-height: 44px;
}

.action ul li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f4f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action-control:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action-control:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.action-control:focus+.action {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <span style="position: relative">
        <a tabindex="0" class="action-control"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
        <div class="action">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="text-menu">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-menu">Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

is there any wrong in my css code? please help me.
i think it's a trivial issue but still can fix by my self.
here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tesarwijaya1205/xwxxpoc8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<tbody>` element has `opacity: 0.84;` set on it.  As such, all its children -- including your popover -- are also at that opacity.  Not sure if this is a mistake or you're trying to accomplish something with this.  If the latter, I'd recommend instead targeting the pertinent elements with a background-color using [`rgba`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) -- this should be easily over-ridden by the `background-color` of your popup.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle after removing opacity on tbody  https://jsfiddle.net/hdas2012/02L5vwo9/1/

Comment: @anied oh, nice catch. i don't realize that would go to all child component.  actually i want that opacity to be applied to the table text. i have over-ridden the opacity on .action-control:focus + .action { opacity: 1} but still don't work and as you suggested i also applied background-color with rgba  to .action it still not override the opacity.

Comment: You can simply use color property to dim the text color. Why to use opacity for this. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/hdas2012/02L5vwo9/2/

Comment: @HariDas thanks. i have solved my issue. as you suggested, i use color property with rgba function to dim the color instead of opacity.